# Maui Listview in proportional grid row in scrollview

Tags: .net, listview, scrollview, maui

I'm using a listview in a grid proportional row, and its other elements are in an auto row. Because I want my listview to take up the rest of the screen. So far everything is normal.

[image]

However, when I want to use a scrollview on the outside, the listview takes up the whole screen and the other elements are not visible.

[image]

I want the listview to appear the same in the scrollview. Here I have to use scrollview because I am adding more elements (label, button, etc.) in grid dynamically. After a while, when the listview height reaches the end, the scrollview should kick in.
I tried everything but failed

Many thanks to those who have helped so far.

Example code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp4.MainPage">
    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <ListView x:Name="listView" 
                          Grid.Row="2" 
                          VerticalOptions="Fill"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                          MinimumHeightRequest="200">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Text="Favorite"
                                      IconImageSource="favorite.png"
                                      Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView}, Path=BindingContext.FavoriteCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                <MenuItem Text="Delete" 
                                      IconImageSource="delete.png"
                                      Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                   Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                                   HeightRequest="60" 
                                   WidthRequest="60" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Text="{Binding Location}"
                                   FontAttributes="Italic" 
                                   VerticalOptions="End" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <Label Grid.Row="3"
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button Grid.Row="4"
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You can check this docs: [ScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview), it talks about `ScrollView` in details.

Answer (score 0):

You want your "listview to take up the rest of the screen", and at the same time, you are wrapping this grid in a ScrollView, removing the limitation.

Do not wrap your Vertical ListView in Vertical ScrollView. Or, if you do, make sure the height of you ListView is limited.

Otherwise you will be scrolling on fully expanded ListView.

Comment: Firstly, thank you.

Because the list view has a minimum height. For example: let's say our screen is 600px height and ListView is in proportional row, other elements are in auto row. When we add 3 elements, each 100 height, the List View should have a height of 300px. But if I add 3 more elements and ListView can be minimum 200pixel, I have to scroll to see the elements that don't fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the row which listview is in to [absolute heights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid#simplify-row-and-column-definitions).

Here is the code:

```
<ScrollView>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto,200,auto,auto,auto,auto">
       <Image Grid.Row="0"
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
       <Label Grid.Row="1"
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="2">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                    <x:String>sss</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
       <Label Grid.Row="3"
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
       <Button Grid.Row="4"
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Image Grid.Row="5"
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
           <Label Grid.Row="6"
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
       </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Yes that is also an option but I have to calculate the remaining height myself. For example, when I add a second Listview and want the first to be 1* and the second to be 2*, calculating the absolute height will be difficult and tedious :)

Comment: Or you can add `HeightRequest` to ListView, and then set its value. I think it is a reasonable approach for now.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I think I need to calculate proportional heights myself and assign the heightrequest myself. Another solution seems difficult.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm calculating the proportional heights myself now.

*The codes were kept simple because it was an example and the ViewModel is not included here.*

If anyone has other ideas, they can add theirs. Thanks everyone.

**This is the final state.**

MainPage.xaml

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Button Text="+ Add Random Element" Clicked="OnAddRandomElementButtonClicked" TextColor="White" />
</Shell.TitleView>
<Grid>
    <ScrollView  x:Name="MainScrollView" VerticalOptions="Fill" Margin="0">
        <StackLayout x:Name="MainStackLayout" />
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    double width;
    double height;
    int count = 0;

    List<MyElement> myElements = new List<MyElement>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();

        myElements.Add(new MyElement(MyElementType.Image, -1, 100, true));
        myElements.Add(new MyElement(MyElementType.Label, 30));
        myElements.Add(new MyElement(MyElementType.Entry, 35));
        myElements.Add(new MyElement(MyElementType.ListView, -1, 200, true));
        myElements.Add(new MyElement(MyElementType.Label, 35));
        myElements.Add(new MyElement(MyElementType.Button, 40));

        SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (Width != this.width || Height != this.height)
            {
                this.width = Width;
                this.height = Height;
                RenderContent();
            }
        };
    }

    private void OnAddRandomElementButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randIndex = rnd.Next(myElements.Count);
        var randomElement = myElements[randIndex];

        myElements.Add(randomElement);

        RenderContent();
    }

    void CalculateProportionalHeightAndUpdate()
    {
        double usedDisplayHeight = myElements.Where(e => e.IsProportional == false).Select(e => e.Height).Sum();
        double leftOverDisplayHeight= this.height - usedDisplayHeight;

        var proportionalElements = myElements.Where(e => e.IsProportional);
        if (proportionalElements.Any())
        {
            double heightForOneUnit = leftOverDisplayHeight/ proportionalElements.Count();
            foreach (var element in proportionalElements)
                element.Height = Math.Max(element.MinHeight, heightForOneUnit); // Minimum height
        }
    }

    void RenderContent()
    {
        CalculateProportionalHeightAndUpdate();

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        foreach (var element in myElements)
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = element.Height });

        int row = 0;
        foreach (var element in myElements)
        {
            VisualElement visualElement = element.ElementType switch
            {
                MyElementType.Label => CreateLabel(element.Height),
                MyElementType.ListView => CreateListView(element.Height),
                MyElementType.Button => CreateButton(element.Height),
                MyElementType.Image => CreateImage(element.Height),
                _ => CreateEntry(element.Height)
            };
            grid.Add(visualElement, 0, row);
            row++;
        }
        MainStackLayout.Children.Clear();
        MainStackLayout.Add(grid); //Since scrollview is not active with dynamic content, I added the grid in stacklayout.
    }

    Entry CreateEntry(double height = 40) => new Entry { Placeholder = "Enter text here", HeightRequest = height, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };

    Image CreateImage(double height = 100)
    {
        return new Image
        {
            Source = "dotnet_bot.png",
            HeightRequest = height,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
    }

    ListView CreateListView(double height = -1)
    {
        var listView = new ListView
        {
            HeightRequest = height,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
        };

        listView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Monkeys");

        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid { Padding = 10 };
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });

            Image image = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill, HeightRequest = 60, WidthRequest = 60 };
            image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageUrl");

            Label nameLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

            Label locationLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End };
            locationLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Location");

            Grid.SetRowSpan(image, 2);

            grid.Add(image);
            grid.Add(nameLabel, 1, 0);
            grid.Add(locationLabel, 1, 1);

            return new ViewCell { View = grid };
        });

        return listView;
    }

    Label CreateLabel(double height = 30) => new Label { Text = "Hello, World!", HeightRequest = height, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };

    Button CreateButton(double height = 40)
    {
        var button = new Button { Text = "Click me", HeightRequest = height, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
        button.Clicked += (s, e) => OnCounterClicked(s, e, button);
        return button;
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e, Button button)
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
            button.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            button.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(button.Text);
    }
}

public class MyElement
{
    public MyElement(MyElementType elementType, double height, double minHeight = -1, bool isProportional = false)
    {
        ElementType = elementType;
        Height = height;
        MinHeight = minHeight == -1 ? height : minHeight;
        IsProportional = isProportional;
    }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double MinHeight { get; set; }
    public MyElementType ElementType { get; set; }
    public bool IsProportional { get; set; }
}

public enum MyElementType
{
    Label,
    Button,
    ListView,
    Image,
    Entry
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have the ScrollView in the wrong level and you shouldn't nest a ListView inside a ScrollView, so better leave out the ScrollView entirely since the ListView provides scrolling capabilities on its own:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitons="auto, auto, *, auto, auto">
    <!-- leaving out irrelevant bits -->

    <ListView Grid.Row="2">
        <!-- leaving out irrelevant bits -->
    </ListView>
    
    <Label />
    <Button />
</Grid>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview

Comment: Hello,
thanks for the answer.
But when I add more elements here and the listview reaches min-length I should be able to move the scrollbar.
This method ignores Listview MinimumHeightRequest and scrollbars do not appear when elements do not fit on the entire screen.
Try adding 2 or 3 more images to the bottom.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Do you know what happens, when you put ListView (Vertical) inside ScrollView (Vertical)?

Comment: @H.A.H. I only showed what's wrong with the above code and provided a solution for the structural issue. Yes, a ListView ideally shouldn't be inside a ScrollView. I'll update the answer anyway. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yes, if you let it expand without limitations, bad things happen. No '*', no FILL, etc. (I use limitation on height and horizontal lists quite often inside such containers, without performance issues.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

My Listview should use the rest of the screen whenever possible, but if elements don't fit on the screen, I need to be able to scroll the entire screen up so that I can see those elements. So I need to add one Scrollview outside of all elements.

Comment: As in your example, I will use the scrollview outside the DataGrid later. Thanks @ewerspej